# Type initializer threw Exception using MVVM in uwp?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

Below the code for developing a simple UWP project using the MVVM concept. I'm struggling to solve a **`System.TypeInitializationException`** thrown on the **`AddEngineerviewmodel`** static property in the **`Locator`** class.

Inner exception pointing to the DataContext line in View.xaml:

> Cannot find a Resource with the **Name/Key primary** [Line: 10 Position: 5]"} ..

Model:

```
public class AddEngineerModel : BindableBase
{

    private string _engrName;
    public string EngrName
    {
        get { return _engrName; }
        set
        {
            _engrName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("EngrName");
        }
    }

    private string _phoneNo;
    public string PhoneNo
    {
        get { return _phoneNo; }
        set
        {
            _phoneNo = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("PhoneNo");
        }
    }

    private string _email;
    public string Email
    {
        get { return _email; }
        set
        {
            _email = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Email");
        }
    }

    private string _address;
    public string Address
    {
        get { return _address; }
        set
        {
            _address = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Address");
        }
    }

    private int _salary;
    public int Salary
    {
        get { return _salary; }
        set
        {
            _salary = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Salary");
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class AddEngineerViewModel:BindableBase
{

    #region Constructor

    public AddEngineerViewModel(IAddEngineerDataService _engineerDataService, IDialogServices _dialog)
    {
        _engineerDataService = new AddEngineerDataServices(new AddEngineerData());
        _dialog = new DialogServices();
        LoadCommand();
    }


    #endregion

    #region Fields

    private static IAddEngineerDataService _engineerDataService;
    private static IDialogServices _dialog;

    private string _engrName;
    public string EngrName
    {
        get { return _engrName; }
        set
        {
            _engrName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("EngrName");
        }
    }

    private string _phoneNo;
    public string PhoneNo
    {
        get { return _phoneNo; }
        set
        {
            _phoneNo = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("PhoneNo");
        }
    }

    private string _email;
    public string Email
    {
        get { return _email; }
        set
        {
            _email = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Email");
        }
    }

    private string _address;
    public string Address
    {
        get { return _address; }
        set
        {
            _address = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Address");
        }
    }

    private int _salary;
    public int Salary
    {
        get { return _salary; }
        set
        {
            _salary = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Salary");
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    #region Command

    public ICommand AddEngineerCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand ViewEmployeeCommand { get; set; }

    private void LoadCommand()
    {
        AddEngineerCommand = new CustomCommand(Add, CanAdd);
        ViewEmployeeCommand = new CustomCommand(Views, CanView);
    }

    private void Views(object obj)
    {
        _dialog.ShowDialog();
    }

    private bool CanView(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private bool CanAdd(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void Add(object obj)
    {
        _engineerDataService.Add_Engineer_Details(new AddEngineerModel { EngrName=_engrName,Email=_email,PhoneNo=_phoneNo,Address=_address,Salary=_salary });
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion
}
```

Locator:

```
public class Locator
{

    private static IDialogServices Dialog = new DialogServices();
    private static IAddEngineerDataService EngineerService = new AddEngineerDataServices(new AddEngineerData());
    private static ISupervisorDataServices SupervisorService = new SupervisorDataServices(new SupervisorData());


    private static AddEngineerViewModel _engineerViewModel = new AddEngineerViewModel(EngineerService, Dialog);

    public static AddEngineerViewModel EngineerViewModel
    {
        get { return _engineerViewModel; }
    }
}
```

app.xaml

```
  <Application.Resources>
    <locator:Locator x:Key="loc"/>
  </Application.Resources>
```

View.xaml

```
<Page
 Datacontext={Binding Source={StaticResources loc},Path=EngineerViewModel}/>
```

Comment: Click 'view detail' to watch the inner exceptions. That quite often gives a good hint at what's wrong.

Comment: Wow, a picture of an exception.  That's not helpful.  But if you look at the picture, there's a link on it that says "copy exception detail to the clipboard".  Now, if you clicked that link, then click the [edit] link, then replace the picture with the text in your clipboard, that would be really helpful.

Comment: Did you use a third party package? Prism or Mvvmlight?

Comment: No, i didn't use a third party packages (Prism or Mvvmlight) @ Sunteen. why Sunteen thats packages are help to me?

Answer (score 0):

what about changing

```
<Page>
 Datacontext={Binding Source={StaticResources loc},Path=EngineerViewModel}
</Page>
```

to

```
<Page Datacontext={Binding Source={StaticResource loc},Path=EngineerViewModel}>
</Page>
```